# Spring MVC 3 for @Autowired Singleton Thread-Safety

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, thread-safety, singleton

Well, I have 3 layers from Controller->Service->Repository made in MVC Spring 3 design. Now, my question is, since the default scope is defined as Singleton, are they thread-safe?

Here is the code look like:

UserController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController extends ExceptionExtension {
     @Autowired
     private IUserService userService;

     @RequestMapping(value = { "/update", "/update/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String updateUser(@RequestParam("email") String eMail, ModelMap model)
        throws Exception {

          if (eMail.isEmpty() || eMail == null) {
              throw new ArgumentIsEmptyException("Required String parameter 'email' is empty");
          } else {
              UserModel userModel = userService.setUser(eMail);

              if (userModel != null) {
                  model.put("roleList", userService.setRoleList());
                  model.put("title", "Update Existing User");
                  model.put("post", "/users/post/update");
                  model.put("userForm", userModel);

                  return "users.update";
              } else {
                  model.put("title", "Update Existing User");
                  model.put("result", "<font color='red'><u>" + eMail + "</u> does not exist in the database.</font>");
                  model.put("flag", "Error");

                  return "users.result";
              }
          }
     }
}
```

UserService.java

```
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private IUserManager userManager;

    public UserModel setUser(String eMail) {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        Entity userEntity = userManager.getUser(eMail);

        if (userEntity != null) {
            userModel.setEMail(eMail);
            userModel.setRole(userEntity.getProperty("role").toString());
            userModel.setEnable((Boolean)userEntity.getProperty("enable"));

            return userModel;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Say, User A and User B are concurrently running the same url but different parameter.
 
User A request => "http://domain.com/users/update?user=myname1@domain.com".
User B request => "http://domain.com/users/update?user=myname2@domain.com".

Since the Controller is singleton, will the User A eMail variable overlaps to the User B one and the vice versa?

I am finding hard to understand on how is the Singleton Thread-Safe working in this scenario. Should my @Service and @Repository declare as @Scope("prototype) so the inner method variables are isolated from new instantiate?

====>

with Scope("request") to my @Service layer, I hitted this error message :/

> 3328 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader -
>   Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'roleController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.company.dashboard.service.IRoleService
>   com.company.dashboard.controller.RoleController.roleService; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'roleService': Scope 'request' is not
>   active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for
>   this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
>   found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Thread Safety depends upon the internal locking of `userService` in case of scope `singleton`

This is what ultimately happens => The same `userSpace` bean is used for both the requests and both requests concurrently access `userService` bean. So the `IUserService` needs to be thread safe for the whole operation to perform well.

Or

> put the scope to `request`.

In which case a new bean is allocated for every request and the whole operation is thread-safe, thanks to thread confinement. Provided you code accordingly in `IUserSpace`

Comment: I don't have private variable in UserService, but it @Autowired to IUserManager respository.

Comment: So, basically I need to add Scope("request") to Service and Repository layers?

Comment: scope request for  IUserService causes that?

Comment: Have scope request for IUserService

Comment: Yea, thread-safe is very important to the singleton-design. Otherwise, everything will be messed...

Comment: This answer is grossly incorrect. It completely ignores the underlying datastore.

Comment: If my transactions are not on these layers, put scope to request is 100% applicable.

Answer (score 0):

if you make any layer scope: prototype, like suggested in the comments, you are merely moving the problem again to the layer underneath.

You need to decide where you want your transaction demarcation. Typically, this is done at the level of calls to a service. Spring can handle that for you.

Controllers, Services and Repositories should usually be implemented in a stateless fashion, that is to say that those classes don't have any instance variables that your methods modify. Else you will become vulnerable to race-conditions. Finally, your datastore must support the use of transactions.

You use the Google Appengine datastore. It has a very specific approach to transactions, unlike any RDBMS. To talk to to appengine from a Java app I recommend 'Objectify'. Start out by reading [about its concepts] (and the the concepts of the underlying BigTable datastore[1](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts).

Comment: thanks for replying me post. Obviously, you see my code don't have any instance variables in Controller, Service and Repository classes. My implementation is Google App Engine with MVC Spring 3. I am not sure MVC Spring can help me to handle transaction at the Service layer. So, I implemented transactions at the datastore/repository layer as I follow the Google App Engine examples to code. What I really worry is the concurrent update issue as I mentioned in my first post. I just want to make sure the data won't cross one another from users.

Comment: I am also having a question about Autowired variable. Is Autowired variable in a class considered an instance variable?

Comment: yes it is, so unless that object's methods are implemented in a thread-safe manner, it is subject to race conditions.

I edited my answer to factor in that you use google appengine, which changes things completely.

Comment: I have my own methods to control over transactions at my repository layer. Everything works great so far. GAE has mentioned about thread-safe but then its thread-safe only apply to static method. While I coded all the layers with non-static methods and I assume they are just non-thread-safety. The issue comes by when the class Autowired variable is equally an instance variable, and I have to change the scope to request when the class variable instantiate.

Comment: I read a lot of Objectify. I see it is great but I still prefer to control the repository layer with my own Google Datastore low level API methods (e.g. UserManager).

Comment: Manager classes don't run any transaction, it only converting the data model to data entity which is ready to do the transaction. I have another static class with static methods (which known as thread-safety for GAE) for doing committing the transaction changes what had been ready to be fired from Manager classes.

Comment: So apparently, Controller->Service->Repository are MVC Spring Components without transactions. But then the beans are instantiate by request scope. The transactions are only done in one shared static class which I can say 100% thread-safe for GAE transaction which claimed by Google. So, beat them if my statement is wrong :)

Comment: My concern originally concern is to avoid object being overlapped to one another with singleton implementation. Correct me if I am wrong. The original Spring MVC is "singleton non-thread-safety" design.